# How to remove this error from autobahn python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, autobahn, autobahnws

I am following the tutorial on Autobahn python from the link below;

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/app/calculator/calculator.py

The code that caused the error is below;

```
runner = ApplicationRunner(router, u"realm1", standalone = not args.router,
      debug = False,             # low-level logging
      debug_wamp = args.debug,   # WAMP level logging
      debug_app = args.debug     # app-level logging
   )
```

The error message is;

```
Using Twisted reactor <class 'twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculator.py", line 117, in <module>
    debug_app = args.debug     # app-level logging
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'standalone'
```

This was mentioned as an issue in Autobahn but I am not able to understand it enough to figure the solution myself as a newbie.
https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/issues/211

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `standalone` argument from the constructor of `ApplicationRunner` and connect to an external WAMP router like [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io) (or any other WAMP v2 compatible from the list [here](http://wamp.ws/implementations/#routers)).